# How to use currentURI to get active tab url of firefox browser

Tags: javascript, html, xul

I am looking for to fetch current tab (loaded or blank ) URL of Firefox browser.
How to acheive this ? using currentURI property in javascript.

Thanks a lot,

-Pravin

Comment: Sorry, ignore my close vote :-) It's just related to the OP's previous question and not an exact dupe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is your code running inside an addon? You could use:
`gBrowser.currentURI.spec`